# Laravel 10.x Localization not working using session

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I have tried several tutorials in the internet but it doesn't work or the language not changing, I already stored the translation into `\lang` directory, and the session is already set [Localization Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INcXX.png)

here is my source code:

This is my controller :

```php
class LocalizationController extends Controller
{
    public function setLang($locale)
    {
        App::setLocale($locale);
        Session::put("locale", $locale);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This is my Middleware :

```php
class LocalizationMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (Session::get("locale") != null) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get("locale"));
        } else {
            Session::put("locale", "en");
            App::setLocale(Session::get("locale"));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is the route :

```php
Route::get("locale/{lang}", [LocalizationController::class, 'setLang']);
```

Language Switcher :

```html
<a href="{{ url('locale/id') }}"><img class="h-5 mt-4" src="{{ asset('images/flag/id_flag.png') }}"
                alt=""></a>
        <a href="{{ url('locale/en') }}"><img class="h-5 mt-4" src="{{ asset('images/flag/uk_flag.png') }}"
                alt=""></a>
```

Translated Element :

```php
<h1 class="font-black lg:text-5xl md:text-4xl text-3xl md:w-[500px] mx-auto">{{ __('home.hero.header') }}</h1>
```

I have tried several tutorials in the internet, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve the problem, I put the middleware classes `\App\Http\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware::class,` into the wrong middleware kernel group.

Wrong kernel group :

```php
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,

        // I put the middleware classes here
        // \App\Http\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

Group that i should put the middleware:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

            // I should put it here
            \App\Http\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware::class,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Language Files: Make sure you have the necessary language files in the resources/lang directory for each supported language. For example, you should have en and id directories with language files like messages.php inside them.

Namespace in Language Files: Ensure that the translations in your language files use the correct namespace. The key in your translation file should match the one you're using in your view:

For example, if your view has:

```
{{ __('home.hero.header') }}
```

Then your resources/lang/en/messages.php file should have:

```
'home' => [
    'hero' => [
        'header' => 'Your translated text here',
    ],
],
```

Clear Cache: If you've made changes to your language files or configuration, clear the cache to ensure the changes take effect.

php artisan cache:clear

```
// Inside LocalizationController
public function setLang($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session::put("locale", $locale);
    dd(Session::get("locale")); // Debug output
    return redirect()->back();
}

// Inside LocalizationMiddleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    if (Session::get("locale") != null) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get("locale"));
    } else {
        Session::put("locale", "en");
        App::setLocale(Session::get("locale"));
    }
    dd(Session::get("locale")); // Debug output
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for helping me, I have already solve the problem, I put the middeware into the wrong kernel middleware group.